# matplotlib setting axes, panning and zooming controls

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, plot, wxpython

I am using wx along with matplotlib, creating a simple scatter plot

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# example.py

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import wx


x = [1,2]
y = [1,2]

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size = (600,300))
        self.CreatePanel()
        self.Show()



    def CreatePanel(self):
        self.mainpanel = wx.Panel(self,style=wx.RAISED_BORDER)

        self.mainpanel.fig = Figure(figsize=(1,1))
        self.mainpanel.a = self.mainpanel.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.mainpanel.b = self.mainpanel.a.scatter(x,y)

        self.mainpanel.canvas = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self.mainpanel, -1, self.mainpanel.fig)

        self.mainpanel.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.mainpanel.sizer.Add(self.mainpanel.canvas, 1, wx.ALL | wx.LEFT | wx.GROW , 5)
        self.mainpanel.SetSizer(self.mainpanel.sizer)


app = wx.App(0)
frame = MainFrame(None, title="My App")
app.MainLoop()
```

The pyplot class in matplotlib provides a direct toolbar, i want to have a similar thing, but there i cannot customise that toolbar,

So i want to know how can i set the x,y limits, pan the plot and box zoom the plot without using that toolbar.

Thanks in advance

PS. I am pretty much a newbie to python and GUI programming so please point any bad code practices i may have followed :P

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add the toolbar from pyplot to wx application:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar

...    
def CreatePanel(self):
    ...
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.mainpanel.canvas)
    ...
    self.mainpanel.sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.EXPAND)
```

**PS.** I don't understand why you have the figure and everything else as attributes to `self.mainpanel`? Doesn't it give you `AttributeError`?

Comment: The idea is to not use that toolbar, and no it doesn't give me attribute error as i created that attribute.. right

Comment: Why don't you want ot use it? If you want to customize it, then subclass it and do everything you want with it.

Comment: for the simple reason that it is a toolbar, i want to be able to enter direct value into a textbox and be able to set those things

Comment: Then have a look at `Axis.pan` and `Axis.zoom` methods in matplotlib.